# Android Studio - how to debug this situation?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

**Preface**

I'm maintaining an app that I inherited from another team

**Scenario**

I understand `ClassCastException` but for the life of me I cannot find where this error is occurring in the code.

```
01-27 14:47:15.839 13272-13272/com.xx.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.xx.android, PID: 13272
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xx.viewmodels.components.AutoValue_SpecialViewModel cannot be cast to com.xx.viewmodels.components.NormalViewModel
     at com.xx.android.viewholders.NormalViewHolder.bind(NormalViewHolder.java:27)
     at com.xx.android.BaseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(BaseAdapter.java:39)
     at com.xx.android.componentfeed.ComponentFeedAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ComponentFeedAdapter.java:123)
     at com.xx.android.componentfeed.ComponentFeedAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ComponentFeedAdapter.java:79)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6541)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5484)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5750)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:611)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1731)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1496)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17938)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1171)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:856)
     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.layoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:63)
     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:136)
     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
    at andro
```

(I'm not sure why the output cutoff at that point)

**NormalViewHolder.java**

*line 27*

```
public class NormalViewHolder extends ComponentViewHolder<NormalViewModel> {
```

*lines 55-64*

```
public NormalViewHolder(final View itemView, final RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool relatedItemsViewPool) {
    super(itemView);
    Dagger.getInstance(itemView.getContext()).inject(this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    adapter = new NormalRelatedItemsAdapter();
    recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(relatedItemsViewPool);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

## Question

The app stops abruptly even with the settings found in my screenshot below. I've set breakpoints all around `bind` and `onBindViewHolder` and followed them as far as they go with no avail. How can I go about tracking down this issue? I was thinking I could move around in a breakpoint to put things together but I'm not having any luck.. Suggestions?

**Extra**

In researching the issue I've adjusted my breakpoint settings to the following with no success:

[image: android studio break points]

Comment: com.xx.android.viewholders.NormalViewHolder.bind(NormalViewHolder.java:27) may i see the line 27? lines 55-64 don't apear is the stack trace info

Comment: @MohammadTabbara I meant to add that in as well, thanks for the reminder

Comment: I have never tried to extend a component that needs the class that is extending that component... Does that even work? But I suspect that is the problem. That kinda makes it seem like an infinite loop or something.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara I had a typo on 27, it's fixed now

Comment: No problem. Good to know. I read model as holder >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was an impossible situation to debug.**

This app was written to leverage dagger modules. In the app there was a line that referenced an incompatible class but in a file that was never even mentioned in the stack trace - making my methods of debugging rather useless.

Ultimately I had to go through *line by line*, manually inspecting every situation. Good old fashioned elbow grease.